# SQL (tsql) - joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I've recently noticed that executing a query with many joins takes much longer execution time than executing those joins one after the other. To be more specific:

```
SELECT a.*, b.A, c.A, d.A
 FROM a
 LEFT JOIN 
 b
 on a.A = b.A or a.B = b.A
 LEFT JOIN
 c
 on a.A = c.A or a.B = c.A 
 LEFT JOIN 
 d
 on a.A = d.A or a.B = d.A
```

Takes an cosmic amount of time to complete, while doing each step of join and saving it to an table, takes really short time. This whole query were working for like 1:30h and not close to complete, while doing (((a->b)->c)->d) took overall like 3 minutes.

What is the reason of this, can anybody help?

Comment: Please, edit your question and explain a little better the option which worked faster for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the query plan
I suspect you are getting into a loop join
It tends to do a loop join whenever you have more than one join condition
Try a hint

```
SELECT a.*, b.A, c.A, d.A
  FROM a
  LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN b
    on a.A = b.A 
    or a.B = b.A
  LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN c
    on a.A = c.A 
    or a.B = c.A 
  LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN d
    on a.A = d.A 
    or a.B = d.A
```

This may work - but I doubt it

```
SELECT a.*, b.A, c.A, d.A
  FROM a
  LEFT OUTER HASH JOIN b
    on b.A in (a.A, a.B) 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the chaining of `join`s in general.  The problem is the `or`.  I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT a.*, coalesce(b1.A, b2.A) as A, coalesce(c1.A, c2.A), . . .
FROM a LEFT JOIN 
     b1
     on a.A = b1.A LEFT JOIN
     b2
     on a.B = b2.A LEFT JOIN
     c1
     on a.A = c1.A LEFT JOIN
     c2
     on a.B = c2.A LEFT JOIN
     . . .
```

This should return similar results if you have at most one match in each of the tables.  Your version can produce multiple rows if each condition in the `or` matches on a different row.